# laravel 6 socialite login facebook / how do i fix Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, laravel-6, laravel-socialite

i want to add login with facebook to my application and i am following laravel doc:
i installed : `composer require laravel/socialite`
then i added to services.php :

```
`'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_CALLBACK'),
    ],`
```

then i copied this in my LoginController :

```
/**
     * Redirect the user to the Facebook authentication page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from Facebook.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $facebookUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        dd($facebookUser);
        // $user->token;
    }
```

Here are my routes :

```
`Route::get('login/facebook', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

`

.env file :

```
    FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=871654966628890
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=never-show-your-secret-key-again
FACEBOOK_CALLBACK=http://ulp-laravel-socialite.test/login/facebook/callback
```

this is my app :

[image]

but I get this error message :

[image: error]

Comment: better hide that client secret, never show your keys.

Comment: Even when it is removed (it probably will), it's better to consider this secret exposed now. It should be deleted, recreated or just be blocked, whatever is possible.

Comment: The error is clear. You only have 'localhost' configured as a domain on Facebook. You are telling facebook to redirect back to `http://ulp-laravel-socialite.test/login/facebook/callback`

Comment: So what should i put in those fiels ?